# Mapbox & D3: How to create proper color scaling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm playing around with a Mapbox map (written in React) that currently gives me the following output:

[image]

My problem: the coloring of the GeoJSON objects is incorrect. It implies that both shapes have values of ~-4. In truth, the left-hand figure has a value of 10, and should be solid blue, while the right-hand figure, with a value of 5, should be blue-green.

Here's the code for the Mapbox GeoJSON layer:

```
export const COLOR_SCALE = d3
  .scaleSequential(d3.interpolateYlGnBu)
  .domain([-4, 16])
  .range([
    [255, 255, 217],
    [248, 252, 201],
    [239, 249, 189],
    [228, 244, 181],
    [213, 238, 179],
    [193, 231, 181],
    [169, 221, 183],
    [142, 211, 186],
    [115, 201, 189],
    [91, 191, 192],
    [69, 180, 194],
    [52, 167, 194],
    [40, 151, 191],
    [33, 134, 185],
    [32, 115, 178],
    [34, 96, 169],
    [35, 78, 160],
    [34, 62, 149],
    [28, 49, 133],
    [19, 38, 112],
  ]);

var layers = [
    new GeoJsonLayer({
      id: "geojson",
      data: data,
      filled: true,
      getFillColor: (f) => COLOR_SCALE(f.properties.growth),
    }),
  ];
```

Here's the code for the color scale:

```
useEffect(() => {
    var colorScale1 = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateYlGnBu).domain([-4, 16]);
    var svg = continuous("#legend1", colorScale1);
  }, []);
```

Where `svg` is used as a React component. Finally, if needed, here's how I define `continuous`:

```
function continuous(selector_id, colorscale) {
    var legendheight = 200,
      legendwidth = 80,
      margin = { top: 10, right: 60, bottom: 10, left: 2 };

    var canvas = d3
      .select(selector_id)
      .style("height", legendheight + "px")
      .style("width", legendwidth + "px")
      .style("position", "relative")
      .append("canvas")
      .attr("height", legendheight - margin.top - margin.bottom)
      .attr("width", 1)
      .style("height", legendheight - margin.top - margin.bottom + "px")
      .style("width", legendwidth - margin.left - margin.right + "px")
      .style("border", "1px solid #000")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("top", margin.top + "px")
      .style("left", margin.left + "px")
      .node();

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var legendscale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([1, legendheight - margin.top - margin.bottom])
      .domain(colorscale.domain());

    var image = ctx.createImageData(1, legendheight);
    d3.range(legendheight).forEach(function (i) {
      var c = d3.rgb(colorscale(legendscale.invert(i)));
      image.data[4 * i] = c.r;
      image.data[4 * i + 1] = c.g;
      image.data[4 * i + 2] = c.b;
      image.data[4 * i + 3] = 255;
    });
    ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

    var legendaxis = d3.axisRight().scale(legendscale).tickSize(6).ticks(8);

    var svg = d3
      .select(selector_id)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("height", legendheight + "px")
      .attr("width", legendwidth + "px")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("left", "0px")
      .style("top", "0px");

    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" +
          (legendwidth - margin.left - margin.right + 3) +
          "," +
          margin.top +
          ")"
      )
      .call(legendaxis);
  }
```

How can I configure `COLOR_SCALE` such that the shapes are properly colored? I suspect the error stems from the `range` values. For context, I got the RGB values from `colorScale1` by iterating using `console.log(colorScale1(i))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coloring "implies that both shapes have values of ~-4" - this is expected given your scale's range.

A [sequential scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleSequential) has exactly two elements in its range array (generally specified with an interpolator rather than an array). Providing an array of more than two elements means *all those beyond the first two are ignored* - so you're interpolating between the 1st (  [image] ) and 2nd ( [image] ) elements in the provided range array - these elements represent values around -4, so everything will look like it is around ~ -4 when compared with a scale that has the intended range ([ [image] , [image] ]) - like the one used in the legend.

*The provisioning of an array to .range will actually cause errors in some versions of d3 - the use of an interpolator only is the much more common approach*

While I can't recreate your exact issue here - recyling the same scale for both (or most simply removing the range values altogether since otherwise the two color scales are identical) should work: you want the same representation for the same values whether in the legend or the map.

Below I use rectangles instead of geographic features, but it should be analagous to your situation:

```js
var legendheight = 100;
var legendwidth = 40;
var colorscale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateYlGnBu)
  .domain([-4, 16]);

var legendscale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([0, legendheight])
      .domain(colorscale.domain());

var canvas = d3
      .select("body")
      .style("height", legendheight + "px")
      .style("width", legendwidth + "px")
      .style("position", "relative")
      .append("canvas")
      .attr("height", legendheight)
      .attr("width", 1)
      .style("height", legendheight + "px")
      .style("width", legendwidth + "px")
      .style("border", "1px solid #000")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("top", 10 + "px")
      .style("left", 0 + "px")
      .node();

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var legendscale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([0, legendheight])
      .domain(colorscale.domain());

    var image = ctx.createImageData(1, legendheight);
    d3.range(legendheight).forEach(function (i) {
      var c = d3.rgb(colorscale(legendscale.invert(i)));
      image.data[4 * i] = c.r;
      image.data[4 * i + 1] = c.g;
      image.data[4 * i + 2] = c.b;
      image.data[4 * i + 3] = 255;
    });
    ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

    var legendaxis = d3.axisRight()
      .scale(legendscale)
      .tickSize(6)
      .ticks(8);
      
      d3.select("svg")
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" +
          legendwidth +
          ",10)"
      )
      .call(legendaxis);
      
      
  d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(d3.range(30).map(function(d,i) {
       return i / 29 * 20 - 4
    }))
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d,i)=>i%10*20+100)
    .attr("y", (d,i)=>Math.floor(i/10)*20+10)
    .attr("width",16)
    .attr("height",16)
    .attr("fill",d=>colorscale(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=500 height=300></svg>
```

Comment: Awesome response – the colored squares along are worthy of an upvote. I'll accept the answer, since the conceptual idiosyncrasies are what I needed to understand. That said, removing `range` didn't work. Seems that I need to do something additional in `getFillColor: (f) => COLOR_SCALE(f.properties.growth)`.

Comment: Andrew's response is great, but yeah I think there's more to do to color the fill of the features.

Does your use case allow you to use Mapbox expressions and the `paint` property to target the feature that you want to color?

I've had luck with continuous D3 colorscales and Mapbox by "zipping" the color scale values into a big long array with the interpolated values to be used for the Mapbox expressions. It's a pretty brute force solution, but it works.

Comment: @mmz does the scale still produce a color? Or does it generate an error? If you replace the provided range with just the min, max values is their at least an improvement?

Comment: It doesn't produce a color. That said, I created a custom function that returns a color per value in the dataset. Again, the biggest help was conceptually understanding how the scaling worked.